# error creating IAM policy example_policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies

I am trying to create bucket policy to grants a CloudFront origin access identity (OAI) permission to get (read) all objects in your Amazon S3 bucket.
But I am facing this error as "An error occurred:

```
 Error: error creating IAM policy example_policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal.
│       status code: 400, request id: 95044f55-e4bf-403e-8233-95964ffe09d1
│
│   with module.iam.aws_iam_policy.s3Frontend,
│   on ..\modules\iam\resources.tf line 65, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3Frontend":
│   65: resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3Frontend" {
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3Frontend" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity $MYID"] # 
    }
    resources = [ "arn:aws:s3:::WebSitefrontend/*" ]  
  }
} 

resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3Frontend" {
  name   = "example_policy"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3Frontend.json
}

output "s3FrontendId" {
    description     = "IDs of frontend deploy artifect on s3"
    value           = aws_iam_policy.s3-Frontend.id
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error `MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal` refers to [IAM identity-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html) created in `resource "aws_iam_policy"`, which cannot contain principal.

You are trying to create S3 Bucket resource-based policy, which can be used in the [aws_s3_bucket_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_policy) Terraform resource. Example usage:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3Frontend" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.WebSitefrontend.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3Frontend.json
}
```